# GIT - msysgit wont ask for password

Tags: git, ssh, msysgit

I have a remote GIT repository (ubuntu) and am working locally on a windows 7. I had this working nicely, and setup SSH keys. At some point in this process I seem to have disabled GIT/msysgit asking for passwords. I now have a new remote git repo (on ubuntu) without keys setup and it wont ask me for my password. I tried

`git clone ssh://<user>:<pass>@<ip>:<myport>/mygitrepopath`

and it doesnt work either. But I can use putty with the same credentials to log in.

**EDIT**

this is the message I was given

```
Cloning into 'myhub'...
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa blah blah blah
Connection abandoned.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll use `ssh://` with a `user:password@host` URL.

If deleting your `known_hosts` file doesn't work (`rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts`), try adding the `ssh-rsa blah blah blah` line to that file (create it if you've just deleted it, he).

That should help.

There should be an option to make git/ssh not abort the connection with an unknown host, but I don't know it.

Comment: was that deleting the hosts from the windows(client) or Ubuntu(server)? In the past I have successfully used the syntax <user>@<host> but it usually asks for a password

Comment: @neolaser `ssh://user@host` is valid, `ssh://user:password@host` I think is not. And you have to do that hosts thing from the client. More specifically, from Git Bash, so it correctly interprets `~`.